# knitr makes multiple figures instead of adding just lines() to axes

Tags: r, knitr

I have a very simple Rnw file:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
<<mychunk, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, fig.keep='all'>>=
plot(rnorm(100),rnorm(100))
lines(c(-1,1),c(-1,1))
@
\end{document}
```

The R chunk

```
plot(rnorm(100),rnorm(100))
lines(c(-1,1),c(-1,1))
```

should just give one figure. Instead, the output tex is

```
\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{figure/mychunk1}
\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{figure/mychunk2}
```

with two separate figures

[image] and [image]

This doesn't happen in all instances of a plot and lines, depending on the arguments, but the code I've given reproduces the problem. It should just have the second figure.

Comment: why are you using `fig.keep = 'all'` without knowing what it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set `fig.keep="all"`, and are getting just what would be expected from that setting! As described in the [the online documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/options#chunk_options), that option "keep[s] all plots (low-level plot changes may produce new plots)".

Try instead `fig.keep="high"` (the default, so you can also get it by just leaving out the `fig.keep` argument) or `fig.keep="last"`, depending on what exactly you want.

Comment: Thank you! I thought fig.keep refers to the plot files kept separately in the figure/ folder rather than in the document. Stupid assumption on my part. Will accept your answer when it lets me.

Comment: Sure thing. If you're going to be using **knitr** much at all, one complete read-through of that linked documentation will repay your effort in very short order.